# Как задать более точный запрос с интервалом дат MySql

Tags: mysql, datetime

Имеется условие выборки окончания действия в данном случае вип привелегий.
Поле `vip_data` типа `datetime`

```
(`vip_data` - INTERVAL 1 DAY > NOW()) AND
(`vip_data` - INTERVAL 2 DAY < NOW())
```

Это условие для отправки письма, мол **завтра** ваши вип привелегии заканчиваются.
Слово **завтра** далеко не всегда является верным, ибо все зависит от нескольких составляющих

- 1 когда запускается скрипт отправки писем
- 2 когда вип привилегии заканчиваются
- 3 сколько раз в сутки запускается скрипт

Если скрипт запускается один раз в сутки мы имеем большие погрешности и даже пропуски отправки писем с оповещением.

Как правильно построить схему оповещения в данном случае?

Как правильно с уже имеющимися записями в базе выбрать те, которые заканчиваются **сегодня**, независимо от того, когда запускается скрипт?

Comment: попробуйте curdate() вместо now() он начало суток даст. и лучше все таки писать `vip_data > now()+inteval 1 day` что бы над полем БД не производилось никаких вычислений, а один раз считалась константа

Comment: _Как правильно построить схему оповещения в данном случае?_ Например, в 0:00 выгребать одним запросом всех, кого надо оповестить, в отдельную таблицу. А с 0:30 по 10:00 рассылать письма, каждые полчаса отправляя 5% случайных из всех выбранных, с удалением их из списка к отправке. В 10:30 контроль, и при проблемах - ручное реагирование.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, в таблицу юзерами или статусами vip_data (если они в отдельной таблице хранятся) обязательно нужно добавить колонку `mail` в которой указано отправлено письмо или нет. 0 - ещё не отправлено 1 - уже отправлено.
Поле datetime значит можно сделать запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `vip_data` <= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

или

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `vip_data` <= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 86400 SECOND
```

Так вы получите тех, у кого до окончания VIP-аккаунта остались сутки или меньше. Отправляете им письмо и меняете колонку mail с нуля на 1. запрос же поменяем:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `vip_data` <= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND `mail`=0

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `vip_data` <= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 86400 SECOND AND `mail`=0
```

Далее в момент, когда он продляет VIP-статус, колоку mail надо снова на 0 сбросить